# How can one create and then use an alias in a function of a sourced Bash script?

Tags: bash, function, alias

I want to create and then use an alias in a function of a sourced Bash script. I've run into Inception-like difficulties and I would appreciate pointers on how to do this properly.

Here's a sample script to source:

```
#!/bin/bash

myFunction(){
    alias zappo="echo"
    zappo
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The only reason I can see for using an alias over a function in `bash` is that the alias will expand after certain `readline` commands are executed (the only one bound by default is `shell-expand-line`, C-M-e). In a non-interactive shell, you have to explicitly enable alias expansion for them to work at all. Just use a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that aliases will have limited functionality for scripting. From the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html):

> In a script, aliases have very limited usefulness. It would be nice if aliases could assume some of the functionality of the C preprocessor, such as macro expansion, but unfortunately Bash does not expand arguments within the alias body. [2] Moreover, a script fails to expand an alias itself within "compound constructs," such as if/then statements, loops, and functions. An added limitation is that an alias will not expand recursively. Almost invariably, whatever we would like an alias to do could be accomplished much more effectively with a function.

I would use a variable for this:

```
myFunction(){
    zappo="echo"
    $zappo "foo bar"
}
```

Or even a wrapper function:

```
zappo() {
    if [ $1 = 'some value'] ; then
        do something
    fi

    # apply out arguments to echo
    echo $@
}
```

now call it like this:

```
zappo log_info "foo bar"
```

Comment: `$zappo="echo"` is not the correct syntax to declare a variable in a shell script. Should be `zappo="echo"`.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for your insights on this.